# Getting Facebook campaign stats

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-insights

I am trying to get the campaign insights(metrics) from all campaign under a Facebook account. I am getting the following error  'Undefined variable: session'(on $request = new FacebookRequest(). My code is below. Please help me resolve. Thanks!
//Initialize a new Session and instanciate an Api object

```js
    $api = Api::instance();

        use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CampaignFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\InsightsFields;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

        $request = new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
       'GET',
       '/act_accountID/insights',
        array(
        'fields' => 'campaign_name,reach,website_clicks,video_avg_sec_watched_actions'
       )
       );

       $response = $request->execute();
       $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
       /* handle the result */

       print_r($graphObject);

      ?>
```

Comment: You haven't defined `$session`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have more code that you are not sharing, the $session variable isn't defined here. You should be passing in a FacebookSession object here. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/5.0.0 for details.